# UICollectionView Displays empty

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

Hi in my application in trying display the `Flickr` images in my `UICollectionView` but it shows a empty View Control

My code for display the `Flickr` images.

```
{
   NSMutableArray *photoURLs;
   NSMutableArray *photoSetNames;
   NSMutableArray *photoids;
}
```

`viewDidLoad` code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{ 
[super viewDidLoad];   
photoURLs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
photoSetNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
photoids = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[self loadFlickrPhotos];
[self.collectionview reloadData];

 }

- (void)loadFlickrPhotos {

    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos&format=json&api_key=a6a0c7d5efccffc285b0fe5ee1d938e3&photoset_id=72157644758906604&per_page=10&nojsoncallback=1",nil];

    NSLog(@"the url string==%@",urlString);
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    NSString *jsonString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

    NSLog(@"the str==%@",jsonString);

    NSDictionary *results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:nil];
    NSArray *photosets = [[results objectForKey:@"photosets"] objectForKey:@"photoset"];

    for (NSDictionary *photoset in photosets) {

        NSString *title = [[photoset objectForKey:@"title"] objectForKey:@"_content"];
        NSLog(@"title==%@",title);
        [photoSetNames addObject:(title.length > 0 ? title : @"Untitled")];

        NSString *primary = [photoset objectForKey:@"primary"];

        NSString *server = [photoset objectForKey:@"server"];

        NSString *secret = [photoset objectForKey:@"secret"];

        NSString *farm = [photoset objectForKey:@"farm"];

        NSString *urlstr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://farm%@.staticflickr.com/%@/%@_%@.jpg",farm,server,primary,secret];

        NSLog(@"your photo id==%@",urlstr);

        [photoids addObject:urlstr];
    }
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [photoids count];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: (UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier =@"Cell";

    imggpolitical *cell=(imggpolitical *) [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath: indexPath];


    cell.imageview.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[photoids objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]]]];

    return cell;
}
```

I have used the above to display the `Flickr` images in `UICollectionView` but its coming as a empty view please tell me how to resolve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you made your ViewController UICollectionViewDelegate and UICollectionViewDatasource?

Comment: @remus s i have already connected the delegate and datasource and in my viewcontroller also i have done that

Comment: Is your Prototype cell's(on storyboard) cell identifier is set to "Cell" ?

Comment: @ShivamMishra i have already set cell as identifier in my storyboard

Comment: are you getting a black screen ?? Try giving color to cells in cellforRow method check whether cells are not getting laid out or images are not getting displayed on cells content view.

Comment: @ShivamMishra  have giving the color to the cell row its not displaying

Comment: That means your cells are not getting laid out. Have you set the flow layout and sizes of flow items on storyboard??
 Also it might be the case that your images are not getting set on image view and thus you are unable to see the color also.
I would suggest that, remove the image view from prototype cell and try giving content view a label or something. Try setting cell's content view's border

Comment: @ShivamMishra i have tried to of removing the image but its still not working

Comment: Ok, so what about the breakpoints? The arrays exist, but are they populated properly? And your cellForItem method looks a bit of a mess - you'll be loading all these images on the main thread - are you sure it's not just blocking while you load dozens of massive images?

Comment: @jrturton ya i have checked with breakpoints   its skiping the code after this line  for (NSDictionary *photoset in photosets) its not excuting the below codes after this line

Comment: Then you've either got no photosets in there or you've made a mistake with the JSON structure and got the keys wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try `[self.collectionview reloadData]`

Comment: where exactly are you calling the reloddata method? Call it after loadFlickerPhotos in viewDidLoad

Comment: i have called after my loadflickr method in view didload its not working

Answer (score 0):

At the end of  -(void)loadFlickrPhotos method, call reloadData on your UICollectionView. You need to tell UICollectionView to refresh its data.

Comment: i at end of loadflickr method i have called the [self.collectionview reloadData] but still its not working

Comment: In your custom UICollectionViewCell did you set imageview  outlet?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that you're assigning a delegate or data source.  Or for that matter, created your UICollectionView.